# How can I hide or remove chart controls(Image for reference) which are visible on chart selection?

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint, powerpoint-addins

Im creating a powerpoint addin using VSTO C# which creates charts by doing some customization in default office charts. Im stuck at hiding the default controls of chart(Image for reference). Tried many things but nothing works.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EVUy.png)

Comment: @Cindy Meister Can u help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Chart controls are a relatively recent addition to the user interface. It appears they haven't been added to the object model yet.